# timeline chart with events

Tags: ruby-on-rails, charts, timeline

For a rails web application I need a timeline with on the top (stacked) bar charts and on the bottom single events that should be recognizably different using e.g. forms (squares, rhombus, circles) and colors.

It's also important that I get some kind of picture back in order to reuse it to build a pdf.

At the moment I do the bar chart part with google charts, but I can't find a way to do the events. Those could also be on a separate chart that I then align in html or the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

have you ever try the highcharts.

Comment: Looking at them now. Quick question: can I receive a jpg or similar to embed in a PDF?

Comment: yes, take a look at the book <Learning Highcharts>, there is a chapter talk about running the highcharts on the server site and write to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of time series with events made with amCharts: http://www.amcharts.com/stock-chart/stock-events/

You can have any number of graphs stacked on each other, if this is what you want to do.

Disclaimer: I am the author of amCharts.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, both Highcharts and AmCharts don't provide for easy Report creation. Major, serverside hacking is involved to get this running (involving putting a JS interpreter onto Heroku). After much reading, I will try to go for a simpler solution using Gruff and sideways stacked bar charts to emulate Gantt. Gruff produces images per default, so that is exactly what I need.